# Android Studio: Allow user to add images to drawable folder?

Tags: android, image, file, drawable

Is there any possibility to allow the app user to add images to the app's drawable folder?

Comment: No. The drawable folder is inside the app's apk file which you can not rewrite at runtime. You should look into saving files on the internal or external storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry. Resources are read only at runtime and cannot be modified. You will have to work with the user-supplied images as files or as pieces of content identified by `Uri` values.